# Ошибка при добавлении товаров в бд

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных, в ней 2 таблицы (category_sklad состоящая из id и name. products_sklad состоящая из id name kolvo category_id). Для добавления товара во второю таблицу используется форма. При попытке добавить в бд данные из формы происходит ошибка. В форме присутствует тег select который берет данные из таблицы category_sklad.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Админ-панель добавления товара</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $db_name = "kaat";
  $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
  mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
 ?>
 <?php
  //Если переменная Name передана
  if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products_sklad` (`name`, `kolvo`, 'category_id') 
                          VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['kolvo']."','".$_POST['category_id']."')");
      //Если вставка прошла успешно
      if ($sql) {
          echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>";
      } else {
          echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
      }
  }
 ?>
 <table>
 <form action="" method="POST">
     <tr>
      <td>Категория:</td>
       <?php
        header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
        $sqll = "SELECT * FROM category_sklad";
        $result_select = mysql_query($sqll);
        echo "<select name='category_id'>";
        while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result_select)){
         echo "<option value = '$object->id' > $object->name</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
       ?>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Наименование:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Количество:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="kolvo" size="3"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Добавить"></td>
     </tr>
 </form>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос - текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ошибка в добавлении появилась из-за непроверенных ошибок на предыдущих строках.

Варианты ошибок:

1. Расширение mysql в PHP устарело и вместо него используется mysqli или  pdo_mysql.
   Решение: переписать код под одно из приведённых расширении.
2. неверный логин или пароль. Решение: установить правильные значения.
3. ошибка выбора дб. Здесь 2 варианта:

   3.1. базы не существует. Решение: создать базу.

   3.2. нет привелегии. Решение: настроить привилегии пользователя.
4. Наиболее вероятное. Название таблицы и полей не должны быть в одинарных кавычках. Т.е.:

   `$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products_sklad (name, kolvo, category_id) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['kolvo']}', '{$_POST['category_id']}')");`

будет верно. Решение: поставить кавычки правильно.

5. Таблицы не существует. Решение: создать таблицу.

А верное решение зависит от ошибки, о которой мы не узнаем, пока вы её не предоставите.

P.p.S. Передавать значения из базы без обработки чревато взломом. Так же желательно закрывать соединение

При неотоброжении русских символов попробуйте поставить запросы перед select_db:

```
query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: @РоманКапустин не за что) В следующий раз выписывайте ошибку, чтобы не пришлось гадать)

Comment: Понятно, а случайно не знаете почему русские символы не показываются? Вместо них ?????

Comment: Кодировка в базе utf-8, в коде тоже utf-8

Comment: @РоманКапустин добавьте 2 запроса после выбора базы, я напишу их в ответе

Comment: И с эти разобрался, все, вроде вопросов не осталось, русский стал отображаться после mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');

Comment: @РоманКапустин тогда попрошу отметить мой ответ решением вопроса

Comment: Для этого лучше тогда использовать `mysql_set_charset`, а не дергать постоянно 2 функции на установку кодировки.